# Retain an item from nested arraylist of a pandas dataframe and drop the remaining

Tags: python

The pandas dataframe I'm working on has a few nested arraylist items and I'm trying to retain just one field in that and drop the rest.
For ex:

```
| vet | year | treated                                           |
| --- | ---- |-------------------------------------------------- |
| xyz | 2017 | [{breed: abc, age: 12}, {breed: asd, age: 8},...] |
| zxc | 2018 | [{breed: cvb, age: 5}, {breed: yuv, age: 4},...]  |
```

to look like

```
| vet | year | treated_breed |
| --- | ---- |-------------- |
| xyz | 2017 | [abc, asd ..] |
| zxc | 2018 | [cvb, yuv..]  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Series.apply` to change each cell of the column

```
df['treated_breed'] = df['treated'].apply(lambda values: [v['breed'] for v in values])
```

Giving finally

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['xyz', 2017, [{'breed': 'abc', 'age': 12}, {'breed': 'asd', 'age': 8}]],
    ['zxc', 2018, [{'breed': 'cvb', 'age': 5}, {'breed': 'yuv', 'age': 4}]],
], columns=['vet', 'year', 'treated'])

df['treated_breed'] = df['treated'].apply(lambda values: [v['breed'] for v in values])
del df['treated']


   vet  year treated_breed
0  xyz  2017    [abc, asd]
1  zxc  2018    [cvb, yuv]
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Throws a warning. But it solves the problem.

Comment: @Nyx what warning ?